# how do I invert my hash (switch key/value) and group by value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I have a hash in rails like so:

```
{"unique_id" => "1",
 "unique_id2" => "2",
 "unique_id3" => "n"}
```

Each unique key has a count that can be a number 1-20. What I would like to do is have a hash that looks like this:

```
{"1" => ["unique_id", "unique_id2"],
 "2" => ["unique_id3"],
 "3" => ["unique_id4", "unique_id5", "uniqueid6"]}
```

How would I go about doing that with a hash?

Comment: can your elaborate little bit more . not sure what you need to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not too hard!

```
hash = { "unique_id" => "1",
  "unique_id2" => "2",
  "unique_id3" => "n"
}
new_hash = hash.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v), h| (h[v] ||= []) << k }
```

`each_with_object({})` is just an each loop with a blank hash

`||= []` means if the hash doesn't have a value for `v`, set it equal to an empty array

`<< k` pushes the key onto the array

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  h.group_by{|k,v| v }.each{|k,v| v.map!(&:first) }
```

`group_by` takes your hash and groups it by value

`each` iterates over the result hash

`map!` maps the first elements of the result value arrays, since `group_by` on a `Hash` returns two-dimensional `Array`s with the structure `[key, value]`